# Loki and GTX 1070: Can't choose anything but 1024x768

Tags: resolution

I've tried adding resolutions via xrandr (VGA1 is apparently not a thing) as well as installing NVIDIA's proprietary drivers (the NVIDIA install fails after a "something something drm service error"). My monitor is 4k and I'm stuck at 1024x768.

**How can I add my monitor's native resolution to the display menu in system settings?**

*RANT: Just as a side note to the project contributors (if they're looking at this), I really want to love this OS but I'm impressed with the fact that Linux has not "handled" the display driver issue and fragility of display control over the past decade since I was last a user. This is pretty bad (yes, there are many hardware vendors and new versions of hardware but there must be a way for the Linux community to get it together on this one).*

Answer (score 1):

The proproetary GPU drivers in the base repo Elementary uses (Xenial)  are too old to properly support the 10 series cards,  try adding the graphics drivers ppa and grab nvidia-370 from there. As I recall,  xenial is locked to the 350 branch,  that branch doesn't support the 10 series line of cards,  they hadn't even been announced back then.